# Do not show all docker containers to a particular user

Tags: docker, virtualization, role-based-access-control

I want to use one server to host multiple docker-containers. I want to give another user a possibility to manage new docker-containers, but I do not want to give him access to all other containers, which I started, since they may contain sensitive data.

Is there a way to create a secure configuration which doesn't require creating virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to DevOps SE!

To enable Role-Based Access Control ([RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)) for Docker Engine, you need the UCP (Universal Control Pane) available through Docker EE.

https://success.docker.com/article/rbac-example-overview

A free alternative could be also the Kubernetes module ***[rbac.authorization.k8s.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)***.

Side note: To control docker commands available to a user, use ***AuthZPlugin*** for the Docker engine (there are open source implementations of this [API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_authorization/)).

Comment: I've read the documentation, but I am still not sure, how this can be done. Would you be able to add some example to your answer?

Comment: it looks like, with both solutions I can only restrict a users access to particular commands. But what I need, is to give full access to some container and none access to others

Comment: yeah...at first glance, this is what I need. But pricing of docker EE...is not acceptable for me :(